# Difference between HTML component and a normal component in Aurelia?

Tags: javascript, aurelia

I'm starting with the standard TypeScript skeleton for my Aurelia development.

I wanted to add some code to the "nav-bar" component, so I decided to convert it from a simple HTML-only component to a regular component. To this end, I modified the *require* tag in my app.html from:

```html
<require from="nav-bar.html"></require>
```

to

```html
<require from="nav-bar"></require>
```

Next, I created a nav-bar.ts file, which contained the following code:

```js
import {autoinject} from 'aurelia-framework';
import {customElement, bindable} from 'aurelia-framework';
// import {HttpClient} from 'aurelia-fetch-client';

@autoinject
@customElement('nav-bar')
export class NavBarClass {
    public attached() {
        console.log("TEST");
    }
  }
}
```

I left the nav-bar.html exactly as is. Now the program runs and the console contains the TEST value from the instantiated NavBarClass, *BUT* the menu that used to be displayed when nav-bar was HTML-only is now missing.

How do I get the menu back? What am I doing wrong? How does a regular component differ from an HTML-only component?

Thanks for your help,
-Greg

Comment: show your nav-bar.html, app.js and app.html. You are probably missing something somewhere.

Comment: @FabioLuz, the nav-bar.html and app.ts files are stock from the skeleton app, here: https://github.com/aurelia/skeleton-navigation/tree/master/skeleton-typescript/src

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In a standard custom element the bindable properties are defined in the view-model:

*nav-bar.js:*

```js
export class NavBar {
  @bindable router;
  ...
  ...
}
```

In an html-only custom element, there is no view-model so the bindable properties are listed on the `<template>` element's `bindable` attribute instead:

*nav-bar.html:*

```html
<template bindable="router">
  ...
  ...
</template>
```

Either way the nav-bar element usage is the same:

```html
<nav-bar router.bind="router"></nav-bar>
```